# Can't unhide grayed out objects

Tags: modeling, interface

After some searching on stack / google I decided to ask this here, this is the second time I'm facing this issue this time with blender 2.8, previously with 2.7 and without a clue to how I got here.

Some of my objects appear hidden(10/12), and I can't seem to find a way to unhide them.

Solutions to the most common rookie mistakes seems to be

- In local-view solved by pressing numpad /
- hidden by pressing H or Shift + H, unhiding with Alt + H

I'm not in local view, I can toggle visibility for 2/12 objects with Shift + H & Alt + H, but the rest stays gray in the collection.

Last time I solved this by exporting the whole model as STL and importing it back again, I then had to re-group all the pieces but there must be a more simple solution.

Here's the .blend if someone wants to have a go at it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qdrsg9u0p11b995/v5.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to go to the filter >>> Globally disable in viewports and turn it on.

[image]

Hope that helps

Good Luck